# phonegap iframe not showing in iOS simulator or device

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe

I'm developing a Cordova / Phonegap app. In some point of my app I load a page where I want a google calendar to be shown so user can see the agenda.

I just copy-pasted the iframe from google calendar, but, while it shows correctly my calendar in browser testing, when I create iOS app, it doesn't show itself, nor in simulator, nor in device.

Why is this happening?

```
....
</div>

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=whitedragongroup%40gmail.com&ctz=Europe/Madrid" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

</body>
```

**PS:**

I tried placing div inside previous div but result is the same.